# Understanding bathroom fan wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring, bathroom, switch, fans

I want to replace existing fan switch in bathroom. I need to identify line, neutral, ground and load. Existing wiring is in the picture. I'm especially confused by green wire because everywhere it says it is ground, but it doesn't look like ground. I'm in Canada in case it matters in term of wiring standards.

[image: existing wiring]

Comment: Can you post a photo clearly showing where the wires enter the box please?

Comment: This certainly has the look of something DIY'd by an immigrant, though where from isn't clear and the green as not ground is uncommon almost everywhere. But the blue & brown and black & red is new and old UK/Commonwealth and perhaps other places live/neutral colors as I understand it. Ah, I see that the PRC uses solid green for phase.

Answer (score 3):

You've got three different things going on that complicate this:

- Conduit

This is both good and bad. It is good because it means you can add new wires as needed (see *neutral* below). It is bad because it confuses people (see *ground* below). It is good because you can use whatever colors are needed, including *extra* colors. It is bad because in this particular case, the colors were not used correctly.

Typical US/Canada branch circuit wiring, outside of places that *require* conduit, is almost entirely done with cables that are either black/white/bare-ground or black/white/red/bare-ground. You have [Joesph's Technicolor Dreamcoat with black and white and red and green and blue and brown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_and_the_Amazing_Technicolor_Dreamcoat). That can only happen with individual wires in conduit.

- Ground

Ground can be bare (what you are used to seeing) and can also be green or green with a yellow stripe. So you have a green ground wire (you may also have metal conduit as ground) but it is currently used as hot or switched hot, which is **wrong**.

- Neutral

Neutral must be white or gray. White in a cable can sometimes be other things. But other colors can't be neutral. So you will need to *add* a white neutral wire. The good news is that you appear to have extra wires, so you should be able to use one of them to pull a white neutral through the conduit.

Since a neutral is not required for a simple switch, it is quite common to not have a neutral in the switch box. Conduit makes it easy to add one.

##### Wire Identification

Since at least some wires are not being used correctly, you will need to identify *all* of them. Figure out where the other ends of the wires are - another switch box, the fan or light fixture box, a receptacle box, some other junction box or the main panel. Once you figure that out, you need to identify each wire. Some wires may be capped off on the other end. Some may be connected to other things. Some may be connected to ground or neutral or the hot terminal on a breaker, etc.

A Non-Contact Voltage Tester is a must, but not a total guarantee of safety. A multimeter will be useful if you are not sure where wires go as you can use it to test continuity with other wires and with ground. (All metal boxes should be grounded, which sometimes helps in figuring out where wires go as ground wires, neutral wires and grounded boxes should all show continuity with each other.)